# Clementine won't play .wma, with "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plugin" error

Tags: 14.04, sound, ffmpeg, gstreamer, clementine

Here's a screenshot: 
[image]

It displays messages like: "Clementine stopped." or displays songs that are not playing, and indicator icon is disappearing and reappearing. Does this happens only to me, or is it common bug in 14.04. I clean installed 14.04, and in 13.10 clementine worked fine. Any ideas? I installed [`ubuntu-restricted-extras`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-restricted-extras).

Edit1: I restarted computer and theme changed:
[image]
[image]

Edit2: I just figured out that clementine won't play .wma files, and that's when errors start to emerge.

Edit3: VLC and the default ubuntu player play .wma without problems. Please help!

Comment: Have you got the packages gstreamer0.10-plugins-good, gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad and gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly installed?

Comment: Yes, it says they're the newest version.

Comment: what are music type are you trying to play? e.g. mp3?

Comment: I'm playing mp3 and ogg files, but clementine plays them. The problem are bugs described.

Comment: if these are indeed bugs, you should report these on launchpad to allow the developers visibility of the issues.

Comment: I will. I just want to confirm am I the only one experiencing these issues.

Comment: Had same issue but with guayadeque... being unable to play .wma files, however installing gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg solved  issue

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**14.04 and later**

I've checked the clementine 1.2.x [dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/clementine) and I can confirm it requires the gstreamer 0.10 plugins and since wma support is provided by the ffmpeg plugin you need to set up the following PPA to enable WMA support for 14.04 and later:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: Here's what I get:
'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-sr
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
'

Comment: Could you try opening the same files with totem (which also use Gstreamer)? It will tell us if it's a Gstreamer plugin missing or a Clementine issue.

Comment: Yes! I just figured out that clementine won't open .wma files. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean that totem can play wma files? `gstreamer1.0-libav` should provide the necessary plugin (avdec_wmav2)

Comment: Yes, totem plays them, but clementine gives errors like on screenshots and wont't play .wma .

Comment: maybe clementine is using the old 0.10 plugins, try to `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`

Comment: Here's what I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' has no installation candidate

Comment: Should I try: 'sudo apt-get purge gstreamer0.10*'? It looks like i have both 1.0 and 0.10 plugins installed. It's perheps some kind of  conflict?

Comment: No, it will remove all the packages/apps depending on them

Comment: Try instead to `rm ~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry*.bin` to see if that works and log out+ log in

Comment: I did that and restarted computer. Clementine gives the same errors. Totem at first refused to play wma, but was succesfull on second try. It might be because I tried to play wma right after restart. Thank you for your support. Any more suggestions? :D

Comment: I've updated my answer with the steps to install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` on 14.04 (it worked for me)

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  Worked perfectly for me as well!

Comment: Some 'Beatles' songs in wma format took me here. Problem solved. I can listen to them now. Thanks Sylvain.

Comment: 14.10 gives me: `Falhou obter http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found` (Falhou obter = Failed to obtain)

Comment: @Sardinha94410: I've updated my answer to use a 14.10 enabled ppa

Comment: @Sylvian Pineau: Of course it doesn't have found it! That piece of code `/trusty-media/`... Thanks for the update!

Comment: I think this answer should be updated to use only the "gstffmpeg-keep" ppa, for all Ubuntu versions, as it contains only the package we need here, and works for 14.04. No need to get all the other updates the first ppa would offer.

Comment: @chtfn: Thanks for your advice (and the confirmation that it works for 14.04). Answer updated

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error on 14.04 LTS when trying to stream any internet source. This is what resolved the error for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Comment: works on 18.04 LTS too

Answer (score 4):

By the way, in my Ubuntu 14.04 (upgraded from 13.10) it seems that there is no *apt-add-repository*

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Now yes, you can install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg as #1 said:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: Weird because `software-properties-common` is part of the default installed packages (See the 13.10 [manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.manifest))

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with clementine and ubuntu 16.04 , although everything was working good before but suddenly m4a songs stopped to work .

I open a single file using the default ubuntu video application it prompts me to install `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad`

so may this command helps you out there

`$ sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad`

Comment: This worked for me.