# How do I install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: 14.10, gstreamer, clementine

Is it possible to install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` needed for Clementine on Ubuntu 14.10? (see [Clementine won't play .wma, with "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plugin" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456072/clementine-wont-play-wma-with-your-gstreamer-installation-is-missing-a-plugi))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user who maintains the PPA mentioned in those answers also has [a PPA exclusively for `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/gstffmpeg-keep). So do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 15.10 one needs to download and install the package manually (see http://askubuntu.com/a/707612/173287).

Comment: @KarlRichter it doesn't look like the package has changed much. Perhaps somebody should email the PPA maintainer requesting a bump in supported releases

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add the PPA, you can simply run this command:

- If your system is **32-bit** *Ubuntu Trusty (**14.04**):

  ```
  wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~trusty2.1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~trusty2.1_i386.deb
  ```
- If your system is **64-bit** *Ubuntu Trusty (**14.04**):

  ```
  wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~trusty2.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~trusty2.1_amd64.deb
  ```
- If your system is **32-bit** *Ubuntu Utopic (**14.10**):

  ```
  wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~utopic2_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~utopic2_i386.deb
  ```
- If your system is **64-bit** *Ubuntu Utopic (**14.10**):

  ```
  wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~utopic2_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~utopic2_amd64.deb
  ```
- If your system is **32-bit** *Ubuntu Vivid (**15.04**):

  ```
  wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~vivid_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~vivid_i386.deb
  ```
- If your system is **64-bit** *Ubuntu Vivid (**15.04**):

  ```
  wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~vivid_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~vivid_amd64.deb
  ```

Comment: Package for 15.04 work for Ubuntu 15.10 as well.