# Ubuntu audio plugins

Tags: files, format, mp3

Hie. My operating system won't play any other audio format except .flac so whenever i try playing playing an mp3 or wma file etc it says could not find required plugin. In need of a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Open a terminal.
In the terminal type:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

You will have to give your password, wait until the installation finishes.
Now you should be able to play mp3, wav etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend also installing VLC (through software center or `"sudo apt-get install vlc"`)
 as it will also support a variety of codecs like (wav, wma) which ubuntu extras does not suffice to play them.

Another way for playing wma files is installing ffmpeg codecs for gstreamer from ppa repositories (which is demonstrated in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/456259/576046))